# The ping response time doesn't reflect the real network response time

Tags: nat, local-area-network, ping, route

I encountered a weird problem that the response time returned by `ping` is almost fixed at `98ms`.

Either I `ping` the gateway, or I ping a local host or a internet host. The response time is always around `98ms` although the **actual delay** is obvious.

However, the reverse ping (from a local machine to this host) works properly.

The following is my route table and the result:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
60.194.136.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

# ping the gateway
ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=98.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=97.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=94.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=94.0 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 94.030/96.149/98.744/1.673 ms 

#ping a local machine
ping 192.168.1.88
PING 192.168.1.88 (192.168.1.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.88: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=98.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.88: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=96.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.88: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.88: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=95.0 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.88 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 95.003/96.696/98.786/1.428 ms

#ping a internet host
 ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.128.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.128.139): icmp_req=1 ttl=42 time=99.8 ms
64 bytes from hg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.128.139): icmp_req=2 ttl=42 time=99.9 ms
64 bytes from hg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.128.139): icmp_req=3 ttl=42 time=99.9 ms
64 bytes from hg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.128.139): icmp_req=4 ttl=42 time=99.9 ms
^C64 bytes from hg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.128.139): icmp_req=5 ttl=42 time=99.9 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 32799ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 99.862/99.925/99.944/0.284 ms
```

I am running `iperf` to test the bandwidth, the rate is quite low for a LAN connection.

```
iperf -c 192.168.1.87 -t 50 -i 10 -f M
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.1.87, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 0.06 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.1.139 port 54697 connected with 192.168.1.87 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  6.12 MBytes  0.61 MBytes/sec
[  4] 10.0-20.0 sec  6.38 MBytes  0.64 MBytes/sec
[  4] 20.0-30.0 sec  6.38 MBytes  0.64 MBytes/sec
[  4] 30.0-40.0 sec  6.25 MBytes  0.62 MBytes/sec
[  4] 40.0-50.0 sec  6.38 MBytes  0.64 MBytes/sec
[  4]  0.0-50.1 sec  31.6 MBytes  0.63 MBytes/sec
```

Comment: Do you experience high delays in other protocols?

Comment: How to test those? I could put the result here.

Comment: For example, you can try to transfer a big file from one machine to another.

Comment: @Khaled: transfering a big file is all about measuring bandwidth, slow start scaling, and window scaling - latency is an important factor in throughput - but far from the only determinant.

Comment: netperf returns latency/RTT information for UDP or TCP workloads. Needs to be run on two machines, though. You do not have some kind of QoS or net delay emulation mechanism in place by any chance? `tc -s class list dev eth0`, `tc -s qdisc list dev eth0`

Comment: @symcbean I agree. And also the problem here is not about real network lag, but the effective measurement provided by `ping`. In the case of `ping google.com` the summarize has **5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 32799ms** but the ping response time is still `98ms`.

Comment: in this case this might simply be a bug in your implementation of ping. Have you tried `traceroute` to see if it exposes the same kind of problem?

Comment: @syneticon-dj thx to the hints. **Firstly of all**, I have enabled QoS on the local route - but as the ping initiated from other local machine works properly. I didn't think it is the cause of the problem. After I turned the QoS down, the same problem persists.  **Secondly**, I tried `traceroute` which works properly with one hop `
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  97.892 ms  97.883 ms  97.876 ms`

Comment: @syneticon-dj I've ran `iperf` and the result is quite low. (5-6Mbps).  Another hint I got is that: when I reboot the machine, the `ping` response and bandwidth is normal. But it will stop responding to `ping` for a while and then start this lagging problem.

Comment: Why you expect different ping times between gateway and a local machine - aren't they on the same LAN segment ?

Comment: @Sandman4 There are on the same LAN `192.168.1.0/24`. I didn't expect a different one but a normal one (98ms) is innormal. But main problem is that even ping to a external service (google.com), the ping value is the same.

Comment: and traceroute to google is also 1 hop ?

Comment: It is something weirdy as every hop costs equally hours. Is there something wrong with the `ping` program?  `traceroute to google.com (74.125.128.113), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  99.774 ms  99.767 ms  99.760 ms
 2  218.249.152.201 (218.249.152.201)  99.777 ms  99.771 ms  99.766 ms
 3  218.241.239.137 (218.241.239.137)  99.760 ms  99.755 ms  99.749 ms
 4  124.205.98.201 (124.205.98.201)  99.708 ms  99.707 ms  99.701 ms`

Comment: Can you try a different machine on that same switch port?  Might be something misconfigured upstream from your machine (like a broadcast storm on the switch, misconfigured STP, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

`ping` will try to do a DNS PTR query for the IP addresses, which may be the delay you're seeing. Run `ping -n` to disable.

You could also be seeing different behaviour for non-ICMP traffic. Try using [hping](http://www.hping.org/) to send UDP and TCP packets on various ports to check this.

Answer (score 1):

iperf udp mode is more representative of the actual frame transition latency and failure rate.

some of the session-oriented tcp tests gloss over loss.

there are also some cool things you can do with iperf like jitter measurements.

http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php